# Is it possible to evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$ without using trigonometric substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

The normal approach to evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$ is using the substitution $x=2\tan\theta$. But I wonder is is possible to do it without using trigonometric substitution? I tried this approach:

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\int\frac{xdx}{\sqrt{x^2(x^2+4)}}=\frac12\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{u(u+4)}}\quad\text{where}\quad u=x^2$$
But I can't see a way to evaluate final integral without completing square and using the substitution $u+2=2\sec t$ (which is a trigonometric substitution!)

Comment: Is $x=2\sinh t$ also a trigonometric substitution (in general sense)?

Comment: @dan_fulea I think so.

Comment: May i start differentiating $\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+4})$?

Comment: @dan_fulea Ok.${}{}$

Comment: Well, this was the formula given in the tables for the integral, as i learned it from the school. Setting $f=\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+4})$ we get immediately:$$f'=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2+4})'}{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\frac {1+\frac x {\sqrt{x^2+4}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+4}}\ .$$

Answer (score 3):

Use an [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) $t=\sqrt{x^2+4}+x$ so $\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}+1=\frac{t}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$ and $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\frac{dt}{t}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\frac 14\frac{(x^2+4)-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\frac 14\left(\sqrt{x^2+4}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}\right)$$

$\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ can be computed using IBP without any trig sub.

For the second part, consider the sub $t:=\sqrt{x^2+4}$ so that $t^2=x^2+4$ and $t\,\mathrm dt=x\,\mathrm dx$

$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}\,\mathrm dx=\int\frac{t^2-4}{t}\frac t{\sqrt{t^2-4}}\,\mathrm dt=\int\sqrt{t^2-4}\,\mathrm dt$$

which is again computable using IBP without any trig sub.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=\frac{t}{2}-\frac2t $ instead to integrate
$$\int \frac1{\sqrt{4+x^2}}dx = \int \frac1tdt=\ln t+C
$$

Comment: How is this different from the answer posted by  @j.g. 17 hours earlier?

Answer (score 2):

$$x=2\sinh{z}\Rightarrow dx=2\cosh{z}dz\\
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4+x^{2}}}=\int\frac{2\cosh{z}dz}{2\cosh{z}}=z+c =\sinh^{-1}{(\frac{x}{2})}+c\\
$$

Comment: Without trigonometric subs

Comment: @SineoftheTime I see your point, but OP didn't rule out hyperbolic substitutions.

Comment: I see, maybe the OP did not actually rule hyp functions, as you said. Regards :)

Answer (score 1):

Put $$x=2t$$

it becomes

$$\int  \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}=$$

$$\sinh^{-1}(t)+C$$

You can use the fact that if

$$F(t)=\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2+1})$$
then
$$F'(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$

Comment: The substitution $x=2t$ is pretty close to the substitution $x=t$...

Comment: @dan_fulea No, it is closer to $ x=x$.

Comment: @hamam-abdallah ... it is still pretty close to $x=t$. It is not closer to $x=x$, which is not really a substitution. But you may consider how close it is to $x=2t$, if in some wrong logic of argumentation you want to start with "No, (but) it is..."

Comment: I put $ x=2t $ to get the well-known  derivative of argsinh. If it makes you laughing, i am happy for you.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the answer, as i mentioned it in the comments, the substitution in
the answer of [J.G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/56861/j-g) has best chances to work, and it works in a line.

Alternatively...
Starting from the last expression in the OP, we may use the Euler substitution
$$
t = \sqrt{\frac{u+4}u}=\sqrt{1+ \frac 4u}\ .
$$
Then we have *formally* successively $t^2=1+\frac 4u$, $t^2-1=\frac 4u$,
$u=\frac 4{t^2-1}$,
$du=-\frac{8t}{(t^2-1)^2}\; dt$.

The substitution from $x$ to $t$ is thus $\color{blue}{t=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}x}$. (Assuming $x>0$.)
Then with the used substitutions
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}
&=\frac12\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{u(u+4)}}
=\frac12\int\frac{du}{u\sqrt{\frac{u+4}u}}\\
&=\frac12\int\frac{-\frac{8t}{(t^2-1)^2}\; dt}{\frac 4{t^2-1}\cdot t}
=-\int\frac{dt}{t^2-1}\\
&=
\frac 12\log\frac{t+1}{t-1}+C
=
\frac12
\log
\frac
{\color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}x}+1}
{\color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}x}-1}+C
\\
&=\log(\sqrt{x^2+4}+x)+C'\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(At the last point we note that $(\sqrt{x^2+4}+x)(\sqrt{x^2+4}-x)$ is a constant.)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+4}} &\stackrel{y=\frac{1}{x} }{=}-\int \frac{d y}{y \sqrt{1+4 y^{2}}} \\
&=-\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{d (\sqrt{1+4 y^{2}})}{y^{2}} \\
&=-\int \frac{d (\sqrt{1+4 y^{2}})}{\left(\sqrt{1+4 y^{2}}\right)^{2}-1} \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{1+4 y^{2}}+1}{\sqrt{1+4 y^{2}}-1}\right| \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+4}+x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+4}-x}\right|+c \\
&=\ln \left|\sqrt{x^{2}+4}+x\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$